# How to include github repository in gradle project

Tags: kotlin, github, gradle

I'm trying to make a library using gradle and including this library in another project using gradle with a github link.

I'm trying this in settings.gradle:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(URI.create("https://github.com/fonnes/JsonKay.git")) {
        producesModule("JsonKay:JsonKay")
    }
}
```

and this in build.gradle:

```
implementation('JsonKay:JsonKay:1.0') {
    version {
        branch = 'main'
    }
}
```

<strike>When trying to build gradle I'm getting: `Could not find any version that matches fonnes.JsonKay:JsonKay:{require 1.0; branch master}.`</strike>

Is it something I'm doing wrong in my local project or this library? https://github.com/fonnes/JsonKay.git

Edit:
I' have changed it from master to main branch. Currently I'm not being able to import the Kotlin file inside the library. I do see the library in project structure of intellij, but not in the dependency list.

Comment: You don't have a branch called `master`. You probably meant `main`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have a branch `master` but `main`. So, this will work already:

```
implementation('fonnes.JsonKay:JsonKay:1.0') {
    version {
        branch = 'main'
    }
}
```

However, you should either define a version (`1.0`) or a `branch`, not both. The version `1.0` will be resolved to a Git tag and defining `branch` will instruct Gradle to checkout the repective branch.

Better:

```
implementation('fonnes.JsonKay:JsonKay') {
    version {
        branch = 'main'
    }
}
```

or for the `1.0` version:

```
// settings.gradle.kts
sourceControl {
    gitRepository(URI.create("https://github.com/fonnes/JsonKay.git")) {
        producesModule("JsonKay:JsonKay")
    }
}

// build.gradle.kts
implementation('JsonKay:JsonKay:1.0')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have applied these changes but it doesn't seem to pull the package. There is no error message on gradle sync but there is no dependency added.

Comment: @fonnes Tried locally, works for me :-)

Comment: Are you sure? I am seeing it in the project structure part of intellij, but it doesn't contain any kotlin files. I am not able to import any file from it. I also tried making a dummy project, and the same thing happends there :(

Comment: Can you please elaborate more @fonnes? If I understood correctly, you want to see the sources of `JsonKay` in IJ?

Comment: Correct! There is one file in the library now which is called JsonEncoder.kt (located: JsonKay/src/main/kotlin/fonnes/jsonkay/JsonEncoder.kt) and I would like to use that in another project. To be able to import in intellij and use it